# How to interpret effect sizes in simr power simulation for mixed models?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, sample-size, statistical-power

I am conducting a power analysis for linear mixed models. I want to know what sample size is needed to find a specific effect size for an interaction. I am testing the interaction effect by comparing a model with interaction term to a model with only main effects.

I do not have any prior data, therefore I am using the `simr::makeLmer()` function to generate a model. I indicate my fixed effects, my random effect, and the standard residual variance.

I found that both the fixed effect of the interaction and the residual variance affect the power estimate. This makes sense to me, yet, it yields the question how to interpret the size of the fixed effect that I specified for the interaction (I scaled all predictors, btw).

Desired output: I want to have an interpretable value of the effect size for which I am running my simulation.

What I have tried so far: I tried to calculate a $f^²$ statistic (see R code below) using the formula I found here (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stata/faq/how-can-i-estimate-effect-size-for-mixed/):

$$ f^² = (R^²_{\text{full}} - R^²_{\text{reduced}})\big/(1 - R^²_{\text{full}}). $$

However, this $f^²$ value I computed did not only depend on the interaction effect and the residual variance but also on the size of the main effects. I am not sure if this is supposed to be like that. It also yielded some plausible but also some very implausible values (extremely low $f^²$ but still high power and in other cases low power for rather high $f^²$).

What am I missing here? How am I to interpret the effect sizes I speficy in `simr`?

My R-Code:

```
# Setup environment
library(simr)
library(future.apply)
library(MuMIn)

# Create dataset for simulation (derived from https://humburg.github.io/Power-Analysis/simr_power_analysis.html)
subj = factor(1:10)
judgments = 1:6  # 3 scenarios x 2 options
subj_full = rep(subj, 6)
judgment_full = rep(judgments, each=10)

# Simulate some continuous predictors
p1 = scale(ifelse(abs(rnorm(60, 0.5, 0.3))<1, abs(rnorm(60, 0.5, 0.3)), 1))
p2 = scale(1 - ifelse(abs(rnorm(60, 0.5, 0.3))<1, abs(rnorm(60, 0.5, 0.3)), 1))
w1 = scale(rnorm(60, 3.5, 0.5))
w2 = scale(rnorm(60, 3.5, 0.5))

covars = data.frame(id=subj_full,
                    judgment=judgment_full,
                    p1=p1,
                    p2=p2,
                    w1=w1,
                    w2=w2)



# Parameter grid for simulation
nsim = 300  # number of simulations per param configuration

n = 200
intercept = 1
fixed_p = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.5, 2)
fixed_w = c(0.01, 0.05, 0.5, 2)
fixed_interaction = c(0.05, 0.1, 0.3)
rand = 0.1
res = 1

param.grid = expand.grid(n, intercept, fixed_p, fixed_w, fixed_interaction, rand, res)
names(param.grid) = c("n", "intercept", "fixed_p", "fixed_w", "fixed_interaction", "rand", "res")


# Function that runs power simulation and returns power and f² effect-size
    simulate = function(n, intercept, fixed_p, fixed_w, fixed_interaction, rand, res){
      fixed = c(intercept, fixed_p, fixed_w, fixed_p, fixed_w, fixed_interaction, fixed_interaction)  # specify fixed effects
      model = makeLmer(y ~  p1*w1 + p2*w2 + (1|id), fixef=fixed, VarCorr=rand, sigma=res, data=covars)  # create lmer model for param configuration
      model_ext_id = extend(model, along="id", n=n)  # extend model to respective sample size
      sim_magnitude = powerSim(model_ext_id, nsim=nsim, test = fcompare(y~p1 + p2 + w1 + w2))  # compare full model to model without interactions
      
      modelNull = makeLmer(y ~ p1 + w1 + p2 + w2 + (1|id), fixef = fixed[1:5], VarCorr=rand, sigma=res, data=covars)  # specify model without interaction to compute effect size
      r_ab = r.squaredGLMM(model)[2]  # R² of full model
      r_a = r.squaredGLMM(modelNull)[2]  # R² of reduced model
      f = (r_ab - r_a)/(1-r_ab)  # f²
      
      return(c(sim_magnitude$x, f))  # return number of significant model comparison tests and effect size
    }

# Do simulation
numCores = parallel::detectCores()
plan(multiprocess, workers = numCores-1)
power_eff = future_apply(param.grid, 1, function(x) do.call(simulate, as.list(x)), future.seed=5)  # Run simulation for each parameter combination
power_eff = t(power_eff)
results = cbind(param.grid, Power=power_eff[,1]/nsim, Effectsize=round(power_eff[,2], 4))  # compute power from absolute number of significant tests
results
```

Some of my simulation results (also note the negative effect sizes):

```
a       b       a:b       power         effect-size
0.01    0.01    0.05      0.4966667     0.0049
0.05    0.01    0.05      0.5166667     0.0060
0.50    0.01    0.05      0.5333333     0.0127
2.00    0.01    0.05      0.5133333     0.0073
0.01    0.05    0.05      0.5100000     0.0047
0.05    0.05    0.05      0.4933333     0.0058
0.50    0.05    0.05      0.5000000     0.0126
2.00    0.05    0.05      0.5100000     0.0073
0.01    0.50    0.05      0.5133333     0.0022
0.05    0.50    0.05      0.4800000     0.0029
0.50    0.50    0.05      0.4366667     0.0088
2.00    0.50    0.05      0.4666667     0.0069
0.01    2.00    0.05      0.4933333    -0.0002
0.05    2.00    0.05      0.5066667    -0.0001
0.50    2.00    0.05      0.5000000     0.0012
2.00    2.00    0.05      0.5400000     0.0034
0.01    0.01    0.10      0.9833333     0.0191
0.05    0.01    0.10      0.9900000     0.0212
0.50    0.01    0.10      0.9933333     0.0319
```